# IntegrationFlow Exception Handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to create a Flow for message as follow:

**TCPinboundAdapter ----> Message Brocker(ActiveMQ)**

**Flow:**

This flow is created in the following way

1. The message is received via TCP connection to TCP Adapter which may be client or server.
2. The message received to TCP adapter is send to JMS Adapter(ActiveMQ Broker).

The code is as follow:

```
@EventListener
public void handleTcpConnectionClientEvent(TcpConnectionFailedEvent event){

     TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcp = (TcpNioClientConnectionFactory)event.getSource();
     System.out.println(tcp); 
     System.out.println("connection exception client :::"+event.getSource());

     this.status = event.toString();

 }
 @EventListener
 public void handleTcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent(TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent event){
     System.out.println("connection exception server :::");

     this.status = event.toString();

 }

 // this method is invoked when the connection with the sever got disconnected
 @EventListener
 public void handleTcpConnectionServerEvent(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event){
     System.out.println("connection exception serversssss :::"+event.getConnectionFactoryName());
     this.status = event.toString();

 }

 //when the connection got established (not for first time)
 @EventListener
 public void handleTcpConnectionCloseEvent(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event){
     System.out.println("connection opened :::"+event.getConnectionFactoryName());
    // status = event.toString();

 }

// create a server connection and flow to JMS  
private void createServerConnection(HostConnection hostConnection)  throws Throwable{
    this.status = "success";

    // IntegrationFlow flow;


IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow;
     IntegrationFlow flow = 
IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.netServer(1234)
             .serializer(customSerializer)
             .deserializer(customSerializer)
             .id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()).soTimeout(10000)))
             .enrichHeaders(f->f.header("abc","abc")))
             .channel(directChannel())
             .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
             .destination("jmsInbound"))
             .get();

           theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("test.flow").register();


           if(this.status.equals("success"))
           createInboundFlow(hostConnection);

          // startConnection(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber());

}
```

**Issue:**

This flow is created successfully and get registered to Application Context when there is no Exception.
But in case When there is an exception i.e (BindException)

1. When creating server to a particular port and the Port is already used
   then it raise BindException then also the flow got registered 
   So, we want that the flow should not be registered when there is exception in any of the flow component below.

   ```
   IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow;
         IntegrationFlow flow = 
              IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.netServer(1234)
             .serializer(customSerializer)
             .deserializer(customSerializer)
             .id("server").soTimeout(10000)))
             .enrichHeaders(f->f.header("abc","abc")))
             .channel(directChannel())
             .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
             .destination("jmsInbound"))
             .get();

         theFlow =this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("test.flow").register();
   ```

There are various Listener implemented to check exception in TCP connection try{}catch() block don't raise any exception.

Please provide a suitable approach to handle Exceptions for adapters currently I am using Listeners for various event to know there is something wrong with the tcp adapters.

After applying this approach provided by Mr. Artem Bilan

`@EventListener
     public void handleTcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent(TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent event){
         System.out.println("connection exception server :::"+event);
         this.status = event.getCause().getMessage();
         AbstractConnectionFactory server = (AbstractConnectionFactory)event.getSource();
         System.out.println(server.getComponentName());
         this.flowContext.remove(server.getComponentName()+"out.flow");
     }`

I am able to remove the flow using FlowId but I am not able to catch the Exception 
The Exception below is printing on the console and can't be handled Even I have changed method to

`private void createServerConnection(HostConnection hostConnection)  throws Throwable{}`

and handled these Exception with try{}catch(Throwable t){} in calling function

`Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Exception is described in more elaborated form in the logs provided below:

```
    2018-05-17 21:01:40.850  INFO 18332 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
    .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : started Co123, port=1234
2018-05-17 21:01:40.850  INFO 18332 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter  : started org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter#3
2018-05-17 21:01:40.851 ERROR 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Error on ServerSocket; port = 1234

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.createServerSocket(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:211) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.run(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:106) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]

connection exception server :::TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent [source=Co123, port=1234, cause=java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind]
Co123
2018-05-17 21:01:40.851  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter  : stopped org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter#3
2018-05-17 21:01:40.851  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'Co123out.flow.channel#0' channel
2018-05-17 21:01:40.852  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.Co123out.flow.channel#0' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-05-17 21:01:40.852  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#11
2018-05-17 21:01:40.852  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {jms:outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'Co123out.flow.channel#1' channel
2018-05-17 21:01:40.852  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.Co123out.flow.channel#1' has 0 subscriber(s).
2018-05-17 21:01:40.852  INFO 18332 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#12
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.run(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.run(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You register an `IntegrationFlow` via:

```
this.flowContext.registration(flow).id("test.flow").register();
```

The same `his.flowContext` bean and that id for the flow can be used to destroy the flow from any other place, e.g. an event listener, when you catch the mentioned `BindException`:

```
    /**
 * Destroy an {@link IntegrationFlow} bean (as well as all its dependant beans)
 * for provided {@code flowId} and clean up all the local cache for it.
 * @param flowId the bean name to destroy from
 */
void remove(String flowId);
```

Comment: TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent is the event listener which is provided in method handleTcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent(TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent ) can be used to discard the flow but how will I get the id if it is not a Hard Coded value "test.flow" . Any particular class in which i can cast the "event". you can take a reference of above provided code.

Comment: please note that my flowId is same as server adapter Id so I want server Id by using it I can remove the flow

Comment: You have this piece of code ` .id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber())`. You can combine this `id` with the `flowId`. Then in the ` @EventListener` from the`TcpConnectionServerExceptionEvent` you get `soure` and cast it into the `AbstractConnectionFactory`, call its `getComponentName()` and extract `flowId` from there to destroy the `IntegrationFlow`.

Comment: I am getting this Exception which can't be handle by Throwable Class  or any   EventListener  $ 'Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.run(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:185)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)'

Comment: That's not readable from the comments here. Please, edit your question and format the StackTrace properly. Would be great to have more for it. Also, please, mentioned what Spring Integration version you use.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for quick response I have edited the Question

Comment: Sounds like your issue has been fixed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/5cdcd81444f908fbe925889f8b48f91bbfe5db5b#diff-d6a711b904c63e5692396ef77fa99063 and has been released with the `5.0.4`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/releases/tag/v5.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: sorry I have missed the version info My spring integration version is 5.0.3 . Let me update the version to 5.0.4.

Comment: Yep! I've compiled the version fro your logs: `at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.run(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.java:106) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]` :-)

Comment: ,Thanks for reply The N.P.E is resolved on upgrading also I have validated the port by using SocketUtils because `this.status` variable is used to check whether everything in right i.e "success" then continue forward. when the exception is raised a new Thread is created `pool-4-thread-1` apart from main thread , In few scenario this thread execute later while the main thread has completed his flow hence it return "success" while having error

Comment: Well, of course you need to take into account the possible async nature of the Spring Integration components and introduce some synchronization barrier to wait for the flow to be finished . The `CountDownLatch` is the good one. Although I don’t think that you need to wait for any status at all: the TCP Inbound is instantly listening component and you may get many messages from the client